# What is the problem with this logic?

Tags: probability

[image: from khan academy]

Probability of choosing 1 boy is 5/7 ;
Probability of choosing 1 girl is 2/7 ;
So choosing 4 boys consecutively is (5/7)^4 .

Maybe this is a dumb question but please help me. I'm trying learn stat for my new career

Comment: After you have chosen the first student, the chance of picking a boy as the second student is no longer $\frac{5}{7}$.

Comment: That would be valid if choosing any child would be an independent event, but you don't return children back after picking.

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: Thanks both of you. It was a bad question

Comment: Actually, no, it was a good question! You showed your thought process, and that is a good thing! Next time, please just ask your question as text, not as a screenshot ([see here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3176/)), that would be even better.

Comment: @StephanKolassa you can maybe convert your comments to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

After you have chosen the first student, the chance of picking a boy as the second student is no longer $\frac{5}{7}$. Instead, it depends on whether you picked a boy or a girl first.

Now, the probability of picking four boys, and boys only, is the product of picking a boy in the first round, then another boy in the second round, and so on - each *conditional on having picked boys before*.